# Configure Self hosted integration runtime for ADF v1

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have installed self hosted IR on my PC and am trying to use it in my ADF (SQL Server to Azure SQL DB) pipeline. When i run the pipeline it fails with the below error.

InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property 'msiAuthenticator' is invalid: 'The required property is not specified. Parameter name:

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the copy tool UI and set up it again.
[image: Copy Data Tool]
did you use the encrypted credential for your linked service, what authentication type did you use ? to know your scenario, I need more information.